# ? symbols from LUA

Tags: string, api, qt, lua

I've registered LUA api function by using:

```
lua_register( luaState, "someFunc", aaa::someFunc);
```

this function has to load a string from the someFunc's argument.

I am doing it with:

```
int aaa::someFunc( lua_State* state ) {
    const char* _arg = ( const char* )lua_tostring( state, -1 );

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

it works ok, until I put to someFunc() some symbols of my language like: ą, ł, ź etc (it's 'a', 'l', 'z' written holding ALT key). For these symbols qDebug( "%s", _arg )* gives me only "?" for them all. How to recognize these values in my program?

For example when I use in my script sendFunc( "Aaś" ) the printed _arg is "Aa?".

*qDebug is from Qt library, it works the same as printf() but outputs to debug window.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "return me" and "gives me"? How are you displaying this information? This sounds like a display problem, not a data problem.

Comment: @Mud I mean when I print _arg by using qDebug( "%s", _arg ) (qDebug() works like a printf) it prints me "Aa?" instead of "Aaś".

Comment: Print where? To a console? Is this a Windows command console? Bash in Linux? Something else entirely? Does it normally support multibyte characters? If we're talking about a command shell, you could try `echo Aaś` and see what it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QT uses Unicode strings. I expect that the string returned from Lua is in some other codepage. You'll need to convert it to Unicode to use with qDebug.

To see what's really in the string (in terms of hex values), breakpoint your code before calling qDebug.

Comment: I did as you said, results for "Aaś": _arg[0] - 65 'A' const char,  _arg[1] - 97 'a' const char,  _arg[2] - 63 '?' const char. That's really strange.

Comment: @tobi, then I guess your Lua "script" needs to be in UTF8 but is probably in another codepage. The ś is getting converted to ? somewhere earlier

Comment: that's really something with coding. I put my someFunc("Aaś") into a text box (where I write my scripts), and printed it with qDebug( ui.textBox->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str() ); and it gave me "Aa?", but now I completely don't know what to change to fix it.

Comment: okay, so now I've pushed it to last step I think. I just wrote qDebug( "ś") and it printed "?". What the hell can I do with such thing?

Comment: toStdString will toss out any chars it can't handle. You need to use something like toUtf8() instead. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toUtf8

Comment: yea, but now it doesn't matter, with just simple qDebug( "ś" ) it prints "?". I tried to change values in Character Set in the project properties, but nothing worked. I'm totally out of ideas.

Comment: you're now fighting the compiler's encoding. Try this... `qDebug("\xc5\x9b");`  - from this handy page: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256

Comment: oh. This, then... `QChar data = 0x015B;  qDebug(QString(&data, 1));` ... and if that works, try just `qDebug( ui.textBox->toPlainText())`

Comment: There was an error, I changed it to: QChar data = 0x015B; qDebug("%s",QString(&data, 1)); but it prints... nothing (only a space). I even started new Qt project and it's the same. I think I will start new topic soon.

Comment: oh my goddess! That worked:  
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1250"));  
qDebug( "ś" ); Thanks I accept the answer, it led me to the real problem, that wasn't problem with LUA.